# Elementary OS keeps reading my USB's format as ms dos

Tags: format

I've been using Elementary OS for at least a week now, and I want to go and try another Linux, but Elementary keeps reading my USB as ms dos and not able to boot from. I keep trying to format it, but it won't change. Yet on Disks, it says it is fat32.
[image]

Comment: Is there some error or is there just no way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the same. You don't need to worry.

Try reading it on a Windows or OSX machine and it'll be readable as FAT32.

Comment: Yeah but that's the thing, not even my bios recognizes it, whenever I do the option to choose where to boot from, it won't show up. I need my bios to recognize it for me to be able to boot from my USB. It'll solve my issue for creating a live USB, but not a USB I can boot from.

Comment: What tool or command did you exactly use to create the live USB?